# How to insert html table data to mysql database

Tags: html, mysql

I have html table like this

```
<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>        
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>      
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to add these html data to mysql table with form submit (this is not the actual table).
This is my image link

http://s11.postimg.org/phkhh2z6b/Untitled.png

and I use this JQuery code to add this table data from the  form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#details').on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    })

    $('#submit').on('click',function(){
        var st = '';
        $('#trtform input[type=text],select,input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
            st = st+ '<td width="150" align="center">'+$(this).val()+'</td>';
            $(this).val('');
        });
        var remove = $('<td />', {text : 'X', 'class': 'remove'});
        $('#details').append( $('<tr />').append(st, remove) );
    });
});
```

Comment: lol dare i ask why you would wan tto store these in the DB and not just the data?

Comment: First I add multiple rows to this table using a form.Then I insert this multiple rows data to the mysql database at once.

Comment: You should store the data in the DB and with however you are pulling data from the DB build the HTML from this, not store html in a DB, this is mad crazy :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to create input fields for your table. And put the whole table into a form. With the submit button everything inside the Form to a script (here something in PHP)

In your example:

```
 <form id="mydata" method="POST" action="save.php">
 <table style="width:300px">
 <tr>
    <td><input name="name" value="Peter"></td>
  <td><input name="lastname" value="Test"></td>        
  <td><input name="age" value="80"></td>
</tr>
 ...
</table>

<input type="submit" value="send Values to my save script">
</form>
```

In your save.php you can easily read out the values with

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

And then save the values to your database.